# Sample mean converges to 1/2 with error less than 0.01 and probability 0.99

Tags: probability, uniform-convergence, uniform-distribution, law-of-large-numbers

The sample mean random variable of $N$ IID random variables with $X_i$ ~ $U(0, 1)$ will converge to 1/2. How many random variables need to be averaged before we can assert that the approximate probability of an error of not more than 0.01 in magnitude is 0.99?

I setup the problem by using the weak law of large numbers like so:
$$
\sigma = \frac{1}{12} \space \mu=\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
P[|S_N-1/2|<0.01] = 1-\frac{(\frac{1}{12})^2}{N(0.01)^2}=0.99
$$
Solving for $N$, I get $6945$ but apparently the answer is supposed to be $5529$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample mean $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $\mu = 1/2$, and variance $$\sigma^2 = \frac{\operatorname{Var}[X_i]}{n} = \frac{1}{12n}.$$  Therefore, the criterion we must use is $$0.99 \le \Pr\left[-0.01 \le \bar X - \mu \le 0.01\right].$$  But since $$\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma}$$ is a standard normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$, we have $$0.99 \le \Pr\left[ -\frac{\sqrt{12n}}{100} \le Z \le \frac{\sqrt{12n}}{100}\right] = 1 - 2 \Phi\left(-\frac{\sqrt{12n}}{100}\right)$$ where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function for a standard normal variable.  This leads to the equation $$n \ge \frac{2500}{3} \left(\Phi^{-1}(1/200)\right)^2.$$  When we look up the quantile function, we have $$\Phi^{-1}(1/200) \approx -2.57583,$$ which gives us $n \ge 5529.08$.

Bearing in mind that this is an approximation since the exact distribution of $\bar X$ is a [Bates distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution), it is important to note that the large sample size $n$ means that the approximation is fairly precise.  Usually, we would round up the sample size $n$ even though $5529.08$ is closer to $5529$ than to $5530$.  However, an exact calculation yields the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & \Pr[|\bar X - 1/2| \le 1/100] \\
\hline
5528 & 0.98999516849251412362\ldots \\
5529 & 0.99000190666215766225\ldots \\
5530 & 0.99000864018063913425\ldots 
\end{array}$$

which shows that $n = 5529$ is the correct answer.

The above calculation may be performed using a computer via the formula

$$\Pr[|\bar X - 1/2| \le 1/100] = 2 F(n, \tfrac{51}{100} n) - 1$$ where $$F(n,x) = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (x-k)^n.$$